# Did the weasels really die?

Tags: who-framed-roger-rabbit

In the world of *Who Framed Roger Rabbit*, it's stated that there was no known way to kill a Toon until Judge Doom came up with the Dip. But near the end of the movie, Eddie Vallant does a song and dance routine that "knocks the weasels dead", complete with angel wings and harps. He does this because earlier in the film, Judge Doom and Smartass (yes, that's really his name) admonished the other weasels for laughing uncontrollably, saying that they could, in fact, die laughing (like their hyena cousins).

Did the weasels die laughing? Did their hyena cousins? Or are the "angel wings" just an affectation that will wear off eventually?

Note that these questions do not apply to Smartass. He was kicked into a large vat of Dip. He ain't coming back, folks.

Comment: Well there is a significant difference between the laughing deaths, and the DIP death. DIP is like being erased from existence for a cartoon, soul and all.

Answer (score 8):

The film's [script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/roger-rabbit.html) would suggest that they did indeed die.

> Roger means it.  The Weasles are laughing so hard they're giving
>   themselves heart attacks. Valiant spins around on the floor like a
>   clock dial gone berserk.
>
> **VALIANT:** *Hoo-hoo-hoo-hoo...*
>
> **One by one, the Weasles keel over... dead.**  Opaque WEASLE SPIRITS
>   leave their bodies with wings and harps, and float heavenward, still
>   laughing.

Comment: I'll accept this if there's nothing new today, especially with the script reference. Hell, I'll upvote for that.

Comment: This answer is incorrect because these are different kinds of dying. What was meant by "no way to kill a toon," and what the Dip accomplishes, is *destroying* a toon. When the weasels die of laughter, they remain conscious and present, just as paler versions of themselves with wings. In fact, they are apparently even still corporeal: one of them intentionally pulls a lever to redirect the machine's nozzle towards the heroes.